# What is the best way to destroy an audionode

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I'm building something which requires the creation and destruction of potentially a lot of audio nodes. As far as I am aware, in order to destroy an audio node it is necessary to:

1. set all references of the node to null or something else
2. call the stop method if applicable
3. disconnect all connections in and out

The first two are simple enough but I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to list all the node's connections and also need to know if anything else is missing from my list. I also need to know how I can detect the existence of an unreferenced audio node

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Comment: The nodes are objects which will dissappear if you delete them f.e. if you pzt them in an array. I Store my node in an array so if i delete the array the nodes die as well. The nodes are as well not what is expensive as RAM. What is expensive is the audio buffer => which destroys itself after it has been played.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the [specifications on the lifetime of an AudioNode](https://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#lifetime-AudioNode):

> An AudioNode will live as long as there are any references to it. There are several types of references:
>
> 1. A normal JavaScript reference obeying normal garbage collection rules.
> 2. A playing reference for both AudioBufferSourceNodes and OscillatorNodes. These nodes maintain a playing reference to themselves while they are currently playing.
> 3. A connection reference which occurs if another AudioNode is connected to it.
> 4. A tail-time reference which an AudioNode maintains on itself as long as it has any internal processing state which has not yet been emitted. For example, a ConvolverNode has a tail which continues to play even after receiving silent input (think about clapping your hands in a large concert hall and continuing to hear the sound reverberate throughout the hall). Some AudioNodes have this property. Please see details for specific nodes.
>
> Any AudioNodes which are connected in a cycle and are directly or indirectly connected to the AudioDestinationNode of the AudioContext will stay alive as long as the AudioContext is alive.

So, from my understanding:

- a playing AudioNode just needs to be stopped.
- others are best to be disconnected.
- it doesn't hurt to disconnect them all.

Comment: Could you please provide examples.

Answer (score 2):

If you simply call `audioNode.disconnect()` with no parameters, it will disconnect all the inputs to the node as well as all the outputs from it.

Comment: Unfortunately, NO. `audioNode.disconnect()` do and only do disconnect from any output it connected to before. No input to the node will be disconnected. See [disconnect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioNode/disconnect) from MDN.
Or write a demo of your own.

Comment: See also: [AudioNode.cpp#686](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/refs/heads/main/Source/modules/webaudio/AudioNode.cpp#686) within chromium.