# Web Audio API: what is the best practice for playing multiple notes with a complex node graph?

Tags: javascript, web, audio, web-audio-api, synthesizer

I want to build a complex generic synthesizer with Web Audio API, and I am not sure how to handle each note:

- A given synthesizer can be built by connecting multiple AudioNodes, and a complex sound can be made of potentially dozens of AudioNodes.
- After playing a given note, all oscillator nodes must be discarded, re-created and re-connected to the rest of the modules.
- But also the nodes that connect to those oscillators to control their parameters, e.g. LFOs, envelope generators, etc. must be disconnected from the old and re-connected to the new oscillators.
- I want to build generic code that can handle any synthesizer graph without previously knowing about its structure.

So for every new note, I am either forced to do very complex tracking of the node graph... or else just re-create all the nodes.
My preference of course is the simple, brute force approach of re-creating **all** the nodes for each note. For complex synthesizers, is it a bad practice? Will it consume too much memory and/or CPU? What is the recommended approach for such scenario?

There is also the alternative of muting the synth at the end of a note, but then the oscillators keep playing for ever, and also there is the "trigger" problem, e.g. on an LFO I want the wave to start at the beginning when the note starts, and I think that can only be done by creating a new oscillator.

Comment: Very related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47352775/what-is-the-best-way-to-destroy-an-audionode

Comment: if you get no traction on this question I would just code up the scenarios you speak of and give them a try ... I do not know how many web audio api oscillators you can run before seeing cpu usage go through the roof ...  I also do not know if those oscillators are more efficient than you rolling your own equivalent multi freq oscillator mesh although if you are targeting mobile you will hit that wall much faster than laptop users would ... sounds like a fun project !!!

Comment: Thank you for your comments... I will start with the "brute force" approach of re-creating the whole graph for each note, just because it's simpler to implement, and see how far it gets me.